# How to monitor free space and automatically delete oldest files on Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-space

I have a software application that continually writes files to disk at high speed. Each file is modest in size (less than 10 MB or so), but they are created every 1-2 seconds underneath a specified parent directory, say, `/data/`. That directory might look like:

```
/data
    /data/subdir1
         /data/subdir1/file1
         /data/subdir1/file2
         /data/subdir1/file3
    /data/subdir2
         /data/subdir2/file1
         /data/subdir2/file2
         /data/subdir3/file3
    ...and so on
```

The subdirectories get created on the fly by the application as well. Since the files get written continually without stopping, eventually the partition that houses `/data` will fill up. When that occurs, I need to continually prune the contents of `/data` to ensure that there is room for new files to be written.

Is there an existing software tool/library that can be used for this task? Ideally I would like some custom control over what criteria are used to determine which files are deleted (perhaps applying priority to certain subdirectories over others), but as a first cut it would suffice to just delete the oldest files underneath `/data` until the disk free space reaches a minimum safe threshold. I assume that this cleanup routine would run periodically, either as some kind of service or via crontab.